# i have to convert these of the following into regular expression... please guide me if its correct or not

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

** Language containing no words starting and ending on “a”**

RE= ba*b (none of the words generated from this expression with end or start with "a")

L={bb,bab,baab,baaab,...}

** Languages containing only words starting and ending on same letter**

RE= ab*a

L={aa,aba,abba,....}

** Language of all words with a appears in pairs only**

re= a*+b*

** Language of all words not ending on “b”**

Re= b*a

** Language of all words  with count of “a “ as multiple of three**

RE= (((a*)*)*)

please tell me if these regular expression are correct or no?

Comment: Perhaps this belongs on another site?

Comment: $\texttt{cs.stackexchange.com}$